# How to resize images by window.resize function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I actually know how to resize an image with responsive design. But, my problem is not simple. I'm using a scale width function of parent div to append width of image like this:

```
function OnImageLoad(evt){somthing....}
<div class="parent">
 <img style="left: 0px; top: -20px;" onload="OnImageLoad(event);" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-pHWQ1Wp63GQ/Uk3TJLa9FbI/AAAAAAAAACg/_JUXOxweYY8/s1600/edu2.jpg" width="270" height="175">
</div>
```

Now, I want run event on image onload="OnImageLoad(envent);" again if window resizing:

```
$(window).resize(function(){ ??? });
```

Check my attached file : [Link](http://www.mediafire.com/?wngm0gg25m3ps1d)

Check fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/h9DEF/2/

Help me to fix it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/, not a file to download.

Comment: Because images were loaded from posts to create the thumbnails. For the insure of thumbnails quality, I must use scale function to generate size of image from parent div. Check my attached file. @Blaze: My english is not quite good. Please skip for small mistake. Thanks

Comment: We're not going to click on your attached file because we have no idea where it goes or what it will do. Furthermore, if and when you fix that external page, this question will no longer be useful to posterity. Add your relevant code directly to the question, please.

Comment: epas: check my updated question.

Comment: @happi you can scale images in CSS using `max-width: X; height: auto;` This will keep your images proportionate and resize by width. Or you can reserve it and use max-height to resize by height. X will be a number in percentage / pixels (you'll have to specify using % or px).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just call your `OnImageLoad(event);` function from within `window.onresize` like so:

```
window.onresize = function(event) { OnImageLoad(event); }
```

Or you can use jQuery (which simply wraps window.onresize):

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event) { OnImageLoad(event); });
```

Comment: Both of those functions will work. They will both call OnImageLoad, and pass the event into it. Try console.log(event); inside either one of those, and if your javascript is running, every time the window is re-sized, the console.log will run.

Comment: Do it how? Actually, I don't understand your intention.

Comment: You want to run the OnImageLoad function every time the window is re-sized, right? The functions in my answer add listeners to the re-size event on the window. Every time the window is re-sized the code inside of the functions will run. If you call OnImageLoad inside of those listening functions, OnImageLoad will be called every time the listener is called.

Comment: Can you help me do with my attached file. I knew your help, but I did it not working. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this javascript, but the event will be different when passed from an image or a resize listener. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/h9DEF/6/ may help you get you toward your goal

Comment: Patrick.Thanks your help. Finally, I fixed my issues by your suggestion. Something is error but thank to I solved it. Thanks so much. I decided to vote you to the best answer.